# BASH script to run tethereal

Tags: bash

I'm looking for ideas for a bash script that runs tethereal -w /path/to/file1.pcap for a limited or specified amount of time before ending and restarting the cmd with a slightly different output file name, so the 2nd file it writes is something like file2.pcap

I was thinking along the lines of a loop of some sort but I'm not sure how to best do this as my scripting experience is limited.

All help gratefully received
Many thanks

farmorg

Answer (score 0):

```
timeout_const=10
for i in {1..5}
do
    timeout $timeout_const tethereal -w /path/to/file${i}.pcap
done
```

Comment: You can also use `for i in {1..5}`.

Comment: That won't work because as soon as you run the 1st tethereal command you won't be exiting it.

Comment: timeout will kill it or not?

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry you are right. Although you have to be careful that by default timeout sends a SIGTERM instead of a SIGKILL so it might be process and discarded by the application (which probably won't happen in this case though)

Comment: I like this idea but when testing it I find that it starts 5 tethereal cmd's simultaneously. How can I make sure only 1 runs at a time?

Comment: It runs serially 

`timeout_const=10
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
        timeout 10 sleep 1 && echo "avb${i}.js"
        echo $i
done`

Answer (score 0):

```
timeout=10 
for i in `seq 1 N` # notice that N we'll be your upper bound
do
  tethereal -w /path/to/file${i}.pcap &
  sleep $timeout;
  PID=`ps aux | grep tethereal | awk '{print $1}'`;
  kill -9 $PID;
done
```

Comment: NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
       Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.

Comment: Yes Boris, like I commented below in your answer you are correct regarding timeout. My mistake.